# findFirst method in Realm?

Tags: cocoa, realm

I'm switching from Core Data ( Magical Record ) to Realm and I was wondering if there was an equivalent of MR_findFirst ?

For now, I'm doing :

```
if ([myRlmObject allObjects].count > 0) {
    myRlmObject *myFirstObject = [myRlmObject allObjects][0];
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify that and just do:

```
[myRlmObject allObjects].firstObject
```